# Enabling Digg, RSS, Twitter, etc.,

Tags: feature-request, feed, twitter, diggbar

Is it possible to subscribe to a question via feeds or other social networkins or is it possible to use services like digg in stackoverflow sites.

If, not is there any future plans to implement these?

**Edit:**

I found exactly what I was looking for in money.stackexchange.com

Here is the screen shot. Hope to see this in all the sites.

[image]

You guys rock :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS is already implemented on questions, but from what I've seen it only shows new answers, not comments.

Eg https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/61825

Twitter spamming apps, facebook updates, and the like might be on stackapps.

Comment: Ho great. Thanks Lord Quackstar :)